# How to enable mouse magnet (sticky edge) in Xfce with dual monitor setup?

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce

I know that Ubuntu / Unity supports this feature. Is there a way to have sticky edges (influencing the mouse pointer) in Xubuntu as well?